# Как печатать на принтере в powershell?

Tags: powershell, печать

нужно, через powershell распечатывать на любом принтере файл с расширением .pdf

Comment: http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/ - почти то, но мне надо на любом принтере печатать, а не только на том, который выбран по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[тут](http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/)